# using pandas to_csv to write the result to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Below is my code which gets the instance name from excel sheet and searches for the instance name in aws account and gets the instance id. So that process is working fine. now i wanted to write the data to csv say like in a csv there has to be two columns with names like instancename and instanceId and the data should be printed in respective columns. please help me in getting the desired output. the csv is overlapped with the data and once opening the csv i can just see the last values in it because my script overrides the previous results.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np
import os
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'example.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel(my_file, sheet_name='Sheet2')

list1 = df['EC2NAMES']
print(list1)
client = boto3.client('ec2')
for names in list1:
    custom_filter = [{
        'Name':'tag:Name', 
        'Values': [names]}]
    print(names)
    instances = client.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
    for instance in instances['Reservations']:
        for key in instance["Instances"]:
            x = key['InstanceId']
            print(x)
            data = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [names],'B' : [x]})
            data.to_csv('df111111.csv')
```

Expected output:

```
Instancename  InstanceID
testinstance  123456
testinstance1 12345656312
testinstance2 12345657237
```

Actual output:

```
Instancename  InstanceID
testinstance2 12345657237
```

Comment: You're overwriting the CSV file each time through the loop.

Comment: You should combine all the data into a single dataframe, then write it to the CSV once at the end.

Comment: post the data please. `data.to_csv('df111111.csv')` overwrites in each iteration the `data` object

Comment: can i write to a different sheet in a same csv using to_csv@Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas `concat` or `append` but best way is to store the data into list and in the end make a dataframe of that and save it as csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np
import os
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'example.xlsx')

df = pd.read_excel(my_file, sheet_name='Sheet2')

list1 = df['EC2NAMES']
print(list1)
client = boto3.client('ec2')
data = []
for names in list1:
    custom_filter = [{
        'Name':'tag:Name', 
        'Values': [names]}]
    print(names)
    instances = client.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
    for instance in instances['Reservations']:
        for key in instance["Instances"]:
            x = key['InstanceId']
            print(x)
            data.append([names, x])
pd.DataFrame(data, colums=['A','B']).to_csv('df111111.csv')
```

Comment: Thankyou poojan for the response but the solution is printing out the same response as before.follwed inputs from Barmar and it worked.

Comment: @sree there was a small bug in code. Fixed it you can run the solution now.

Comment: Is this because storing data as a list is less intensive than using pandas append? @Poojan

Comment: Yes append method on pandas data frame is definatly a lot expensive than just appending data to list.

Comment: @Poojan This is good to know, some of files are rather large, this may help

Comment: can i write to a different sheet in a same csv using to_csv@Poojan

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes a new 'data' variable for every iteration of the for loop. My attempt is making a blank data variable before starting the loop. Add a new piece to the dataframe each loop, and once you're out of the loop you save it to csv

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
list1 = df['EC2NAMES']
print(list1)
client = boto3.client('ec2')
for names in list1:
    custom_filter = [{
        'Name':'tag:Name', 
        'Values': [names]}]
    print(names)
    instances = client.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
    for instance in instances['Reservations']:
        for key in instance["Instances"]:
            x = key['InstanceId']
            print(x)
            data = data.append(pd.DataFrame({'A' : [names],'B' : [x]}))
data.to_csv('df111111.csv')
```

Comment: I would like to Thankyou for the quick response but making the changes is creating a blank df111111.csv

Comment: I think my mistake was with the second to last line, made a small change, basically I appended to the data variable but without data = data.append(...) nothing was being returned

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thankyou Barmar

Comment: see poojans comment below as to why his  method is better